# What does "Fn::Join" refers to in a config file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am new to Serverless but take a look at this config file

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

# you can add statements to the Lambda function's IAM Role here
#  iamRoleStatements:
#    - Effect: "Allow"
#      Action:
#        - "s3:ListBucket"
#      Resource: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", { "Ref" : "ServerlessDeploymentBucket" } ] ]  }
#    - Effect: "Allow"
#      Action:
#        - "s3:PutObject"
#      Resource:
#        Fn::Join:
#          - ""
#          - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
#            - "Ref" : "ServerlessDeploymentBucket"
#            - "/*"
```

Does this resources refers to [fnproject](https://github.com/fnproject/fn)?

I looked at [aws-resource-type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) but could not find reference information.

Comment: `Fn::Join` is a cloudformation intrinsic function which joins strings to create a single string. There's plenty of documentation on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fn::Join` is an intrinsic function, and it appends a set of values into a single value, separated by the specified delimiter. If a delimiter is the empty string, the set of values are concatenated with no delimiter.

You can use different intrinsic functions inside *join* and [pseudo parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) as well.
For more information check the [official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html)

Answer (score 1):

`Fn::Join` is a function in CloudFormation to concatenate strings. `Ref` is another function to reference elements created in CloudFormation.

In you example, `Fn::Join` is used to concatenate strings to create the **ARN** of the S3 bucket, whose format is **arn:aws:s3:::bucketname** and is needed to give permissions to the bucket in Lambda.